# $fpdf->Output( 'D', "filename.pdf") return pdf string to browser instead of forcing download

Tags: php, laravel, pdf-generation, laravel-8, fpdf

I merged multiple pdfs using fpdf, storing it locally to a path works fine. I want to skip storing and download the pdf straight from memory.
I used the following in a service :

```
//All had the same outcome (returned pdf string to the browser *see imager)
$fpdf->Output( 'D', "filename.pdf")
$fpdf->Output( 'I', "filename.pdf")
$fpdf->Output( 'S')
```

[image: Network Tab Response]

Using:

- PHP 7.4
- Laravel 8
- setasign/fpdf (1.8.6)
- setasign/fpdi (v2.6.0)

I tried:

```
$fpdf->Output( 'F', "path/filename.pdf")
return response->download("path/filename.pdf")

$output =  $fpdf->Output( 'S');
        
return Response::make($output, 200, [
       'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
       'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="merged.pdf"',
       ]);
```

same issue, it returns the pdf string to the browser.

Comment: Are you using AJAX to send the request to the server?

Comment: @ADyson I'm using axios.

Comment: Well then, that's the reason. AJAX requests don't cause downloads by default. In that scenario the data sent by the server is sent into a JavaScript variable, it doesn't get downloaded to the user's machine. That's true no matter how you generate the content on the server side.

Comment: No problem. P.S. I rolled back your edit. You don't need to put the solution in your question because 1) the solution is already in the duplicate question, which is linked from here, and 2) logically, an answer is not part of the question - stackoverflow keeps these things separate :-)

Comment: `window.location = 'some URL'` is all you need. Why write complicated code when you can do it in one line?

Comment: @Oliver window.location works for a special download file request, in my case I get application/json or application/pdf as response.

Comment: @alex I'd say it's a design flaw for one script or route to be able to return multiple different content types. It makes it less flexible and harder to process the response. It should consistently return a file, or consistently return json

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify the response headers, not the content alone.
2. Your Browser may also interfere, when being set as default pdf viewer.

When the response headers tell you,

> Content-Disposition
> attachment;filename="xy.pdf"

then you are okay.